# Remove duplicate code with similar factory classes

Tags: c++, templates, factory

I have this code:

```
struct Foo1 {}
struct Foo1Helper {} // generated

struct Foo2 {}
struct Foo2Helper {} // generated

struct Foo1Factory {
    Foo1* Create(){
        return connect();
    }
protected:
    Foo1 *connect();
}

// cpp file (important because i don't want to have Foo1Helper in .h file)
Foo1* Foo1Factory::connect(){
    return Foo1Helper::doSmth();
}

struct Foo2Factory {
    Foo2* Create(){
        return connect();
    }
protected:
    Foo2 *connect();
}

// cpp file (important because i don't want to have Foo2Helper in .h file)
Foo2* Foo2Factory::connect(){
    return Foo2Helper::doSmth();
}
```

I have two classes Foo1 and Foo2, and both are created with a factory class with the help of the Foo1Helper and Foo2Helper classes.

The idea is to somehow have just one Factory class because there is a lot of duplicate code, the only difference is the helper function which is called in the connect function.

Note: I want to hide the Helper classes from the header files so the connect function must be implemented in .cpp file.

Comment: what is the question? This code has too many errors to make any sense to me

Comment: This question makes more sense than [its predecessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989222/template-parameter-name-concatenation-in-c), but it is still foggy. You have two factories, each of which direct object creation to distinct helper classes, each of which generate distinct object types dynamically. I suppose you could jam either template specializations or some function overloads in there somewhere, but the actual end-goal is still not entirely clear. Sooner or later `Foo1Helper` and `Foo2Helper` have to be distinctly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one Factory if you can live with defining some aliases and you can  hide your Helper classes in cpp if you can live with some explicit template instantiations. And I don't see why you wouldn't.

In the following I made the assumption your factory methods are static. If they are not, it can be easily adapted with the pimpl idiom.

#### header file

```
struct Foo1 { /* implementation */  };
struct Foo1Helper; // just declaration

struct Foo2 { /* implementation */ };
struct Foo2Helper; // just declaration

// a little helper
template <class Foo_main, class Helper>
struct Foo_trait
{
    using Foo = Foo_main;
    using FooHelper = Helper;
};


// this section can be easily generated
// if you have a lot of classes and feel particularly lazy
using Foo1_trait = Foo_trait<Foo1, Foo1Helper>;
using Foo2_trait = Foo_trait<Foo2, Foo2Helper>;


// just one Factory class
// no implementation exposed to the header
template <class Foo_trait>
struct FooFactory
{
    using Foo = typename Foo_trait::Foo;
    using FooHelper = typename Foo_trait::FooHelper;

    static auto Create() -> Foo*;
};
```

#### source file

```
struct Foo1Helper
{
    static Foo1* doSmth()
    {
        static Foo1 f;
        return &f;
    }
};

struct Foo2Helper
{
    static Foo2* doSmth()
    {
        static Foo2 f;
        return &f;
    }
};


template <class Foo_trait>
auto FooFactory<Foo_trait>::Create() -> Foo*
{
    return FooHelper::doSmth();
}

// explicit template instantiation
// very important. Without this you get linker erorrs
// again very easy to generate
template struct FooFactory<Foo1_trait>;
template struct FooFactory<Foo2_trait>;
```

#### usage

```
Foo1 f1 = FooFactory<Foo1_trait>::Create();
Foo2 f2 = FooFactory<Foo2_trait>::Create();
```

---

If you have control over `FooN` then you can skip the `Foo_trait` altogether and define an alias inside `FooN`. E.g.

```
struct Foo1
{
    using Helper = Foo1Helper;
};
```